# How to get pod names from inside and the pods names form another namespace in Kuberentes?

Tags: javascript, python, kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

Assume I am running a Javascript server in a Pod in Kubernetes. How can I get the name of that pod or its ID?

Similarly, if I am running a Python server in namespace A, how can I get the names resp. other IDs of all pods in namespace B?

Comment: Please read: [Can I ask only one question per post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post) --- For question 1, there are way to pass the pod's name as environment variable into the pod. For question 2, we'd most probably need to interact with the kubernetes API.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the name of the pod as seen inside the Kubernetes Cluster by checking the `HOSTNAME` variable inside the pod.

Ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/container-environment/

For your second question, you can always run kubectl inside a container running in the cluster. Check this question:
[Run kubectl inside a cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50569471/run-kubectl-inside-a-cluster)